# Unknown CMake Command QT4_ADD_RESOURCE

Tags: cmake, qt4

Very new to make files here, so please forgive me if this is a noob question. I can't seem to find the answer on the internet.

I've forked a public repository from github, and it repository itself is supposed to be download, make and run, but I've already fixed a half dozen errors in their make files trying to get it running. Now I'm down to this one, which seems to be something to do with CMake not finding the right QT4 command.

When I'm in a build folder, the instructions (according to the owner of the repository) says to type "cmake .." - which is an obvious reference to CMakeList.txt in the parent folder. The file is [hosted on Github](https://github.com/RMIT-RoboCup-Standard-League/PP1-Nao-Soccer/blob/master/utils/offnao/CMakeLists.txt), the line that throws the error is line 94, it says:

```
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(OFFNAO_RES_SRCS ${OFFNAO_RES})
```

I am trying to build this program on Ubuntu 14.04.5 (because that's the OS it was originally built on, I can work on upgrading that after it is working). 
The error text it spits out is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:94(QT$_ADD_RESOURCES):
    Unknown CMake command "QT4_ADD_RESOURCES".
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have installed qt4-dev-tools (which also installs all qt4 libraries). 
I can't seem to find how to get CMake to recognise QT4 and its commands.

I'm new to CMake and this is the first time I've come across QT4 so I don't know what I'm looking for. Happy to provide any more info if needed. All help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's the contents of the offnao CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0 FATAL_ERROR)
PROJECT(OFFNAO)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CTC_DIR}/libnaoqi/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CTC_DIR}/zlib/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CTC_DIR}/../sysroot_legacy/usr/include)

SET(OFFNAO_CXX_SRCS
   utils/OverlayPainter.cpp
   // contents skipped for brevity
   tabs/teamBallTab.cpp
)

SET(OFFNAO_MOC
   readers/reader.hpp 
   // contents skipped for brevity
   tabs/teamBallTab.hpp
)

if(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
  list(APPEND OFFNAO_CXX_SRCS tabs/cameraTab.cpp)
  list(APPEND OFFNAO_MOC      tabs/cameraTab.hpp)
endif(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)

SET(OFFNAO_UI
   visualiser.ui
   ConnectionBar.ui
   tabs/LogTab.ui
   tabs/LogsTab.ui
)

SET(OFFNAO_RES
   resources/visualiser_resources.qrc
)

# build cxx files for resources
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(OFFNAO_RES_SRCS ${OFFNAO_RES})

# build ui_XXX files from the XML-style .ui files
QT4_WRAP_UI(OFFNAO_UI_SRCS ${OFFNAO_UI})

# this moc's the above variable and appends to the cxx sources
QT4_WRAP_CPP(OFFNAO_MOC_SRCS ${OFFNAO_MOC})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(offnao.bin ${OFFNAO_CXX_SRCS} ${OFFNAO_RES_SRCS} ${OFFNAO_MOC_SRCS} ${OFFNAO_UI_SRCS})
cotire(offnao.bin)

set_source_files_properties(
   tabs/graphTab.cpp
   tabs/plots.cpp
   tabs/walkTab.cpp
   tabs/zmpTab.cpp
   main.cpp
   visualiser.cpp
   ${OFFNAO_MOC_SRCS} #too lazy to split and list them
   PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-I${QWT_INCLUDE_DIR}")

find_library ( QGLVIEWER_LIBRARY NAMES QGLViewer qglviewer-qt4 )
find_package ( OpenGL  REQUIRED )
find_package ( PNG     REQUIRED )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
   offnao.bin
   ${QT_LIBRARIES}
   ${QWT_LIBRARY}
   ${QGLVIEWER_LIBRARY}
```

Furthermore, the README that states to build this is rather vague, it doesn't actually say what folder to run these commands from. It states:

```
Welcome to Off-Nao, the rUNSWift debugging toolsuite.

To build this project, either:

You get lucky and bin/build_setup.sh just works :D
(verified under Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS both natively and in VMs; 
but builds successfully then segfaults at runtime in libGL.so.1
under fresh download of 14.04.3 LTS @ 15/9/2015 
according to gdb - so much for Ubuntu being stable).

---OR--- 
You need Qt4 and probably a bunch of other things like QGLViewer to build it natively:

    $ mkdir build
    $ cd build
    $ cmake ..
    $ make
    $ ./offnao

Once you have performed the steps above once, in future you only need to:

    $ make
    $ ./offnao

In the 'build' directory
```

I do get the segfault as mentioned in the README at LibGL.so.1 so I've attempted to follow the instruction below it. I can only get the the "cmake .." stage and that's where I get the error.

Comment: According to the [README](https://github.com/RMIT-RoboCup-Standard-League/PP1-Nao-Soccer/blob/master/utils/offnao/README), you should use the script `bin/build_setup.sh`. Anyway, maybe you don't have this module in your cmake: [FindQt4.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindQt4.cmake)

Comment: I am missing the call to `find_package(Qt4 ...)` in your CMakeLists.txt. You need it to get access to the macros QT4_ADD_RESOURCES, QT4_WRAP_UI, and QT4_WRAP_CPP. Please always include the relevant information directly in your question, i.e. by providing the contents of CMakeLists.txt not only by linking to it.

Comment: Are you trying to build only the directory offnao? It looks like the CMake files are not prepared to handle that out of the box. If you want to build the entire repo go to the top level folder and call `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..` in that order. If that's not your intention and you want to build offnao  only you need to add the content of the file PP1-Nao-Soccer/utils/bootstrap-qt.cmake starting from `find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)` to your CMakeLists.txt file in the offnao directory.

Comment: @Tarod That's only the first part of the README. build_setup.sh has already been run. Unfortunately the build_setup.sh will only compile the offnao component in version 14.04.1 of ubuntu, where other areas of this program require version 14.04.03 and 14.04.5. So I'm using 14.04.4. In the README regarding the offnao, it says that offnao on versions 14.04.3+ will require seperate compilation with all this other stuff.

Comment: @vre That's exactly what was missing. Thank you. If you write it up as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. I found the correct syntax [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindQt4.html) after googling from your comment.

Comment: @vre Your second comment may have some merrit. After adding the find_package(Qt4 ...) line to the rUNSWift/utils/offnao/CMakeLists.txt file, attempting to rebuild the entire project fails at that exact line. Why? I don't know. Perhaps there needs to be an if statement to see if Qt4 has already been loaded.

Comment: You need to do the same for Boost. `if (Boost_FOUND) message(STATUS "Boost already loaded proceeding") else() find_package(Boost COMPONENTS iostreams REQUIRED) endif()` before the call to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})` Furthermore you need to add QtNetwork and QtOpenGL to the required Qt modules. And instead of using ${QT_LIBRARIES} you need to reference the imported targets (Qt4::QtXml ...) in your target_link_libraries call as the documentation states. Dont forget to add settings for QWT from the bootstrap-qt.cmake. Make sure you clean the cmake cache after making those changes.

Comment: BTW which version of CMake are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reformulating my previous comment as answer:

To use macros QT4_ADD_RESOURCES, QT4_WRAP_UI, QT4_WRAP_CPP and others you need to call `find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)` first in your CMakeLists.txt. See the documentation for the FindQt4.cmake module (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindQt4.html).